# Error : app:dexDebug finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

hello i get this error, which i have no idea how to fix.

these are my gradles:

```
app gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daniel.testing6"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    //configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}

backend gradle:
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
project gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

does any one know how to fix it???

Comment: okay .please set buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" and set  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'

Comment: Cleaning the project might work. No need to change those versions

Comment: @TimCastelijns Sir ,But rc2 is not stable .I guess its related with this .

Comment: And what is the use of lowering the play version? None I guess

Comment: use gradlew assembleDebug --info and push the log

Comment: i've cleaned the project and its seems to work :)

Comment: soloution: go to Build->Clean Project, and build/run your app again

Comment: however i got the same problem again, so it might be a temp solution..

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Mariotti  hi how do i do that?

Comment: @dan In Android Studio you can use the command line terminal.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ok just write there "dradlew"? what is the entire command?